# Querying an API, and displaying it's results from from form input - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am not sure if I am going about this correctly, but I am not getting any errors it just reloads the page without displaying anything.

The issue could be with me trying to format the api string and input the users input there?

I also tried returning the variable as an HttpResponse, still made no difference.

Sorry just getting back into python, and just starting with Django.

Correct code should go something like this:

1.User inputs their name into the form
2. Page then displays the usersid.

Code:

views.py:

```
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from .forms import SearchUser
import json
# Create your views here.


def home(response):
  #  data = requests.get(
    # 'https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/ReallyBlue/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-6c5d9a2c-3341-4b0c-a0a5-7eafe46e54cf')
  #  userid = data.json()['puuid']
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {
        'form': SearchUser(),  # include reference to your form
        'userid': search,
        # 'mmr':NA,
    })


def search(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            user = n(name=n)
            user.save()
        data = requests.get(
            f"https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/'{user}'/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-6c5d9a2c-3341-4b0c-a0a5-7eafe46e54cf")
        userid = data.json()['puuid']
        return HttpResponse(userid)
    else:
        form = SearchUser()

    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"userid": userid})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class SearchUser(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=200)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name=""),
path("", views.search, name=""),
]
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}


{% block content %}
    <h2>Valorant Ranked Checker</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit" name="search">
            Get rank
        </button>
    </form>
    <p><strong>{{userid}} - {{mmr}}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Blue's Valorant Ranked Checker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content" name="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you dont get any error, because error is happening inside the HTML. I think instead of `views.home`, you need to execute the `views.search` for `""` url path. And are you sure `data` is correct? It seems like the URL is wrong and you are trying to use `f` strings but got the wrong variable (`user`). And then ofcourse, you will also have to pass the `form` onto the template inside the context dictionary for `search` view

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I know the api is correct, because if I run the commented out code ( without trying to get it into a variable I can query the json and get it to display ) I have the api took out the url here for the post. What variable should I be using instead of user then? Also can I call two different view functions for the " " path, or should I be throwing it's own python file and importing it?

Comment: Nevermind I see it should be userid, still same-thing with the correct variable, added the views.search to the urls and still same issue.

Comment: The API is correct. But the URL you use in the commented code is different from the URL you use in the `search` function. To begin with, remove the `f'...'` in the URL and put in the beginning of the URL, that is how `f` strings work. And no, you can't map multiple views in one url. What are you trying to imply with `user = n(name=n)` ?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I see okay, and I am trying to imply that name = the form input after the post method is received, but I think I should probably change name to user. Basically assigning n to user. So do you think it would be best to create a completely different python file to handle the api, because I will need to be plugging in user input, as well as passing it to other apis after the fact.

Comment: Yes so, you have to think the flow of data and then make a view like that. Is `name` from the form, same as the `userid`?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria So yes better to just handle everything api related in different file and import it as a module? Also I'm not sure if I understand is name from the form same as userid, I would like to save, the users input, and assign it to a variable then plug it into the api. In the HTML it's userid.  Updated code to show code again.

Comment: Where do you intend on saving? Did you make a model?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Will I need a model if I just plan on instantly taking the input and then displaying the result? I didn't plan on saving any user info in a database, from my understanding I wouldn't need a model.

Comment: You just said, "_I would like to save, the users input_". If you dont need to save it in a database, then no, you dont need a model

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Didn't exactly mean it as in literally save it sorry. Just simply take the user input, and plug it into api. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245899/discussion-between-delrius-euphoria-and-blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have to do is, use a single view for the url and then do the API querying inside that view. So something like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.search, name=""),
]
```

and then inside your view, you need to send the `form` with the context dictionary to show it in the HTML.

```py
def search(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]

            data = requests.get(
            f"https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/{user}/NA1?api_key=*******")
            userid = data.json()['puuid']
            return HttpResponse(userid) # Or preferably pass onto a different view
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form is not properly filled")
    else:
        form = SearchUser()

    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form": form})
```